# Are there plans to support "type providers" for Scala's SIQ (ScalaIntegratedQuery) like in F#?

Tags: database, scala, f#, scalaquery, type-providers

The current state of SIQ was [presented](http://scala-integrated-query.googlecode.com/files/SIQ-Scala-Days-final.pdf) by Christopher Vogt at [ScalaDays 2011](http://days2011.scala-lang.org/node/244).
It was shown how queries would work and look like, but as far as I remember there was no notion about how those types would be represented, e. g. if it is still necessary to write boilerplate code to explain the database structure to Scala.

F# 3.0 adds [type providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) (PDC talk by Don Syme: [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT12); GOTO Copenhagen talk by Tomas Petricek: [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GOTO/GOTO-2011-Copenhagen/Accessing-loosely-structured-data-from-F-and-C), [slides](http://slidesha.re/llTgVk), [blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/goto-loosely-structured-data.aspx)), which make it basically unnecessary to manually write or generate mappings between a DB (or another data provider) and the language/type system, because the language can query structural information from the database itself directly with type providers.

Will ScalaIntegratedQuery be able to provide the types/relationships of a database to the Scala compiler without requiring the user to write boilerplate code themselves?

Comment: @Carsten: sometimes there is inside information or early reports from the team's work, so he asks. Who knows, maybe the Scala designer will come in an give a good answer.

Comment: @Carsten: I got an answer directly from the guy working on F# type providers in my other question ... go figure.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to my talk, but the essential source of information about F# type providers should be Don Syme's talk. I just played with it, he designed it :-). See e.g. PDC: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT12 but the new one from BUILD may be available too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is YES. We will offer an automatic solution, without manual boilerplate. The current SIQ prototype uses code-generation, but this aspect is not very developed yet, which is why I did not show it at Scala Days. Work on SIQ resumes, when Stefan Zeiger and I start our jobs in Lausanne on 3rd of October. We will review F# type providers for further inspiration. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant! Thanks! But please make sure the technique you use doesn't preclude using it for other things like XML schema definitions or WSDL files. (Another interesting approach you may want to look at is Gosu's "Open Type System")

Comment: "this aspect is not very developed yet, which is why I did show it at Scala Days" are you missing a _not_ somewhere?

Comment: I think as of this writing, type providers is no longer being offered as a language feature.