# Scala Bean Coercion :: The Missing LINQ

Tags: scala, casting, dns, resultset

**Update**

Play 2.0's Scala version will feature [ANORM](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/anorm), which seems similar to Querulous in that both are JDBC wrappers and not ORMs.  Here's ANORM query coercion at work with a parser combinator:

```
SQL("""
        select * from Country c 
        join CountryLanguage l on l.CountryCode = c.Code 
        where c.code = 'FRA';
    """
    ).as(
        str("name") ~< spanM(
            by=str("code"), str("language") ~< str("isOfficial") 
        ) ^^ { 
            case country~languages => 
                SpokenLanguages(
                    country,
                    languages.collect { case lang~"T" => lang } headOption,
                    languages.collect { case lang~"F" => lang }
                )
        } ?
    )
```

The multi-line query """ sql """ is nice, I like that, but the coercion, please, no ;-) In Groovy, bean coercion with the same query is a 1-liner:

```
List[Country] c = sql.rows("select * from country")?.collect{ it.toRowResult() as Country }
```

the null safe operator (?.might-be-null) in groovy is quite convenient, scala seems to require the Some() Option[] combo to deal with possible null outcomes.  Do Scala coders like null handling in Scala?

I guess the general thrust of this post is: can Scala provide scripting language concision while retaining compiler type safe code? Given that Scala is perhaps more powerful/expressive than C# (unintentional flame), then a full blown Scala LINQ must be possible. Furthermore, since Scala straddles the functional and OO paradigms, then it must also be able to achieve Groovy level concision (for example, the 1-liner query-bean-coercion above).

If these assumptions are true, then why do the existing scala ORMs and jdbc wrappers require so much boilerplate compared to groovy and LINQ on C#? Obviously I am an idealist looking for bare bones DSLs where implementations are either incredibly concise, or closely mirror the underlying language they represent (as in LINQ-to-SQL).

**Original**

Have been taking a run through the various Scala ORMs (squeryl, daomapper, couple others will fill in later) and SQL helper frameworks (querulous so far)

Being new to Scala and strongly typed languages in general, one thing that leaps out at me is the need to specify the type (String, Int, etc.) of each column in every query result.

About to get on an overnight train here, but this struck me just now, so putting it out there (will add some examples when I get back online again to make this a bit of less of a ramble)

For now, a quick one from Querulous's readme on github:

```
val users = queryEvaluator.select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (?) OR name = ?", List(1,2,3), "Jacques") { row =>
  new User(row.getInt("id"), row.getString("name"))
}
```

While I understand that the compiler needs to know the type of every "object" you work with, it seems non-DRY to have to specify "row.getInt('id')" when the domain class itself already declares that id is of type Int.

So, coming from a fair degree of ignorance, I will ask, why do Scala ORMs and SQL helper frameworks not provide developers with an implementation model that allows for inferred or implicit result sets?

Just to put in context, I am coming from Grails, which has an, imo, excellent domain/validation model among other framework nice-to-haves, but suffers from dynamic language time wasting fat-finger typing (startup time is painful as well) which is why I am exploring Scala frameworks.

Comment: if you dont have scala types in your entities, you can use a java ORM framework (e.g. hibernate)!

Comment: I'm not sure how your question applies to Squeryl.  A typical query would be of the form from(entity)(e => where(e.value === "something") select(e)) or from(entity)(e => where(e.value === "something") select(e.otherValue)).  In both cases Squeryl returns the proper type without you having to explicitly specify it.

Comment: @aishwarya, right, but then you have to drop down to xml if you go with straight hibernate. Part of what makes GORM, the grails ORM, so good is that the developer just works with the domain class and schema mapping, no xml at all, hibernate is effectively hidden as far as modeling is concerned.

Comment: @DaveWhittaker, yes, Squeryl, for scala ORMs is the best implementation I have seen yet. I guess the syntactic sugar of groovy with its optional parens, free form closures (see grails mapping {}), built-in beans and property interception (for bean validation), etc. had me both spoiled and at risk (since you get little to no compiler syntax checking). I'm looking for an "ideal" implementation, which is arguably LINQ-to-SQL a la Scala, not quite there yet in terms of a crystal clear noise-free implementation. It will come, scala is exploding with the help of inventive minds (and no M$ budget)

Comment: @virtualeyes, not really, you can use annotations so not much XML really. Plus with JPA, quite a bit is inferred and needs no configuration at all on entity basis. There is a general system configuration which would be required in any case.

Comment: @aishwarya, sure, but take an annotated JPA class and compare that to a Grails domain class.  Which is more readable and which one requires zero xml config? JPA may work just fine, but have heard, like Hibernate, that when complex queries are required, it becomes more hindrance than help. In any case, I'm here to explore what Scala has to offer in terms of ORMs, JDBC wrappers and frameworks. Groovy + Grails + Spring + Hibernate is a powerful combination, but not without issues (most notably missing type safety and dog slow startup)

Comment: @virtualeyes Optional parens are a Scala feature as well (each Squeryl operator is in fact a method call) and the closure syntax is not that different from Groovy (substitue map for collect and _ for "it" in your example above, looks like scala code to me). On the Null safe operator, personally I like Option better as it allows you to chain Optional values (option1 orElse option2) and specify alternatives when no value is available (option3 getOrElse 4).  It seems like Squeryl doesn't fit your needs in some way and I'd be interested to hear why you feel it falls short.

Comment: @DaveWhittaker, yes, new to scala but saw the relation between "_" and groovy's "it", cool, love scala's concision with type safety. As I said, Squeryl is the best scala ORM I have run across, I've just been spoiled by groovy and the DSL-esque nature of the language, where parens are often optional, null is handled with a single character (?), and other syntactic sugar. So, I come to Scala with Groovy/Grails/LINQ-to-SQL colored glasses, and am looking for a Scala framework and ORM that provides this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Scala Integrated Query](http://code.google.com/p/scala-integrated-query/) as I understand it is scheduled to be integrated in the [typesafe stack](http://www.typesafe.com/stack) as Scala Language Integrated Connection Kit ([SLICK](http://scalaquery.org/doc/ScalaQuery_Commerzbank_2011.pdf))

[image]

Comment: Good news, SIQ development appears to be full speed ahead as of October 3rd (when Vogt and Zeiger started working in Laussane, presumably for Scala Solutions): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429999/are-there-plans-to-support-type-providers-for-scalas-siq-scalaintegratedquer

Comment: and +1 for the sick link (SIQ LINQ)